# SQL Server query xml get node

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

This query returns the attribute value "storedId1"

```
SET @xml = N'<Data>
                <Ref ID="1" sf="storedId1">
                this is the value I want
                </Ref>
            </Data>'

SELECT 
    T.C.value('@sf', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS result
FROM  
    @xml.nodes('Data/Ref') T(C)
WHERE
    T.C.value('@sf', 'nvarchar(MAX)') = 'storedId1'
```

How can I return the node value instead .i.e. return "this is the value i want"

I guess I need to change the SELECT to something like

```
SELECT T.C.value('Data/Ref', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS result
```

But it fails with

> XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    T.C.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS result
FROM  
    @xml.nodes('Data/Ref[@sf="storedId1"]') T(C)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @xml xml   
SET @xml = N'<Data>
                <Ref ID="1" sf="storedId1">
                this is the value I want
                </Ref>
            </Data>'

SELECT 
    T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS result
FROM  
    @xml.nodes('Data/Ref') T(C)
WHERE
    T.C.value('@sf', 'nvarchar(MAX)') = 'storedId1'
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7540/28512